# Import by name in Spring Java configs

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

Say I have 3 Spring/Maven projects:

- `api-spec`: Contains interface `MyService`.
- `api-impl`: Contains class `MyServiceImpl` which implements `MyService`. Also contains class `MyServiceConfiguration` which is a Spring `@Configuration`, that defines a bean of type `MyServiceImpl`.
- `main`: Contains a Spring application setup with Spring JavaConfig (e.g. a `@SpringBootApplication`). It has a bean with an `@Autowired MyService myService` field, which works as its configuration class is annotated with `@Import(MyServiceConfiguration.class)`.

I would like the `main`-project to have `api-spec` as a Maven `compile` dependency and to have `api-impl` as a `runtime` dependency (to prevent us from making "hard" dependencies from the `main` project to the `api-impl` project by mistake). This is not possible, because `@Import` takes an array of `Class`es - e.g.: `@Import(MyServiceConfiguration.class)`. I would like something like `@Import("my.package.MyServiceConfiguration")` instead.

Using class path scanning is not an option (we have seen too many beans getting picked up by accident), and I would prefer not having to use XML files. We could use `SpringApplicationBuilder.source(..)` as it accepts a class name as a String - but I can't find a way to use that in my tests...

Answer (score 0):

Compile time check is one of the advantages of java config, so I don't think that it's possible to do such thinks with Java. As for me you should use XML to handle this. It doesn't mean that you should do all your configuration in XML, most of the beans of your `api-impl` module can be in Java and just imported to XML where will be only beans that you are going to change in runtime.

If you don't want to use XML maybe you should consider to use Groovy config instead:

https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/03/groovy-bean-configuration-in-spring-framework-4

Comment: I want to use Java Config.